# Errors in the Android Project that just created from IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

The errors are the following:

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [clean, :app:compileDebugSources]
Information:2015/9/16 10:48 - Compilation completed with 3 errors and 0 warnings in 5s 714ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\DevelopProgramPackage\AndroidSDK\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
F:\work\Workspaces\IntelliJWorkspace\AndroidTest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

The target sdk is v21, and the minimun sdk is v19. And whatever the version I choose, I don't know why that IntelliJ generate the v23, this is very annoying.

How to solve that?
I have all versions of the sdks installed, and the solutions on the internet are totally helpless.

Comment: change ur target sdk version to 21 to incoporate material theme

Answer (score 0):

change manifest and build.gradle minSdkVersion compileSdkVersion and targetVersionSdk accordingly else go to style.xml 
and 
use Theme.AppCompat.Light 
also 
in you application tag in manifest